# IsInstance in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to do isinstance/issubclass in a Django template?  I realise I can write my own templatetag, but I'm surprised this isn't possibly which makes me think I'm either doing something wrong or missing something obvious.

I wish to display two different segments of markup, depending on which type of item I'm displaying whilst iterative over my collection.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all of these inherit from a common base type, but you need to know which type it is, you may want to just implement a method on the base that returns the type - then you can call `if foo.get_type == 'type1'` (or whatever) in your template.

Answer (score 12):

I think a simple template filter here fits the best. It is really quick to implement and easy to call. Something like this:

**in templatetags/my_filters.py:**

```
from django import template
from django.utils.importlib import import_module

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def isinst(value, class_str):
    split = class_str.split('.')
    return isinstance(value, getattr(import_module('.'.join(split[:-1])), split[-1]))
```

**in your template:**

```
{% load my_filters %}

...

{% if myvar|isinst:"mymodule.MyClass" %}
...do your stuff
{% endif %}
```

Although the above is a sample code (not tested), I believe it should work.
For more information on custom template filters please see [the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters)

**EDIT:** Edited the answer to show that the filter argument is actually a string and not a python Class

Comment: Having to refer to the full path of a model makes this solution fragile to refactorings in the backend, plus it requires the template/html designer to know these paths. Not the best way to do it if your team is split into backend programmers and template designers.

Comment: I totally agree. The intention here is to answer the question; this is clearly not the best practice for doing conditional stuff in your templates.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something here: the only logic in the template is supposed to handle template rendering. `isinstance` / `issubclass` clearly smell like view logic, and should be in the view. If the template rendering depends on those functions (which I guess it does), you should implement the logic in the view, and just pass the template what it needs to know:

```
# in the view:
if isinstance(some_obj, SomeClass):
    do_fancy_template_stuff = True
else:
    do_fancy_template_stuff = False

# in the template:
{% if do_fancy_template_stuff %}
    <fancy_template_stuff />
{% endif %}
```

Remember: the django templating engine was created having non-programmers, like designers, in mind.

Comment: Hmmm, I agree with the sentiment in general, but I'm not so sure I go as far as taking it as far as this.
  
My use case is, I have a collection of items, all of a common base type, but mixed within the collection.  A foo should display like this, a bar should display like that, kind of similarly, but slightly differently.
  
They have slightly different fields to display, hence the differing display fragments, so it's tempting to say {% if item.field_that_bars_have %} or similar, but that seems nasty.

Comment: I guess the correct way to handle this is to create a custom tag, render_result_item, or something which can pick the correct display fragment.  That way the logic stays out of the view template, although at the expense of putting it somewhere that our non-programmer/designer won't be able to find it.

Or I could write an isinstance templatetag.  Or I could add a get_type or something to the model.

I'm rambling now - thanks for your response :).